# Why did a moderator delete this post?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

On this question, [How do you force Chrome pages/tabs to crash using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965987/how-do-you-force-chrome-pages-tabs-to-crash-using-javascript), my answer:

[image: screenshot]

Was deleted. Why? I can see that the question asks for a "javascript way", but two other answers do not involve javascript (including one with 8 votes and no downvotes), and in the comments the OP shows that he does not need it to be javascript but just wanted to force a crash to experiment.

Sorry this is old, but it just came to my attention now when I was looking for it.

Comment: @derp Yeah, but maybe someone can point out if there was a reason for deletion that I'm not aware of :P I wish there was an explanation, like on edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to have been deleted in response to a "duplicate answers" system flag. Since this was a pretty long while ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483104/purposely-crash-chrome-tab-for-chrome-extension/11588312#11588312)'s the other answer you posted.

We prefer marking the questions as duplicates instead; with your current rep, you should be able to do that now.

Comment: Ah, I see! (didn't know this was wrong behavior). How is that done?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: Ah, nevermind, thought you were talking about marking an answer as duplicate.

Comment: That's done automatically by the system. Marking questions is done manually.

Comment: So Bill didn't actually delete my answer? I would think sometimes two questions might accomodate nearly identical answers (in the past I had searched for other questions a couple of times to see if I can provide the same answer, admittedly for rep).

Comment: He did. Usually, if two questions accommodate nearly identical answers, they are better served as duplicates instead. If you feel that the two questions are different enough that an answer to one could not sufficiently address the other, it's best that you tailor each answer specifically for each question.

Comment: I see. There must be other answers of mine deleted from that time then :P Ah, the wonders of trying to earn internet points. Thanks though, you cleared this out for me :)